# Perl/MariaDB: conflict with decoding (execute failed: Incorrect string value: '\xE4...')

Tags: perl, encoding, mariadb, dbi, diacritics

I extract data from html-files with perl and want to insert the data into a database. But there is a strange behaviour with umlauts (ä,ö, ...).

The setup is:

```
use DBI;        
use DBD::mysql;
use HTML::Entities;

$name = ... # extraction from html-file

my $dbh = DBI->connect ("DBI:mysql:db_0",
                        "root", "mypw",
                        { RaiseError => 1
                          , PrintError => 0
                          , mysql_enable_utf8mb4 => 1
                        }
                        ) or die "Fehler beim Verbindungsaufbau zum MariaDB-Server:" .
                                 " $DBI::err -< $DBI::errstr \n";


my $insert_import = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO arzt_0 (name) VALUES (?));
$insert_import->execute($name)
or die "Fehler bei der Ausfuehrung: ".
   "$DBI::err -> $DBI::errstr (stage_imports $DBI::state)\n"
   ;

$insert_import->finish();
```

Database has character set utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Since the content of the scalar $name has html code for umlaute, for example `&#196;` for `Ä` I used

```
use HTML::Entities;
```

to change the html code to character `Ä`:

```
$name = decode_entities $name;
```

For example, the origin content of `$name` was  `&#196;rztin` and after decoding `Ärztin`.

If `$name` is exported to the terminal (`print $name`) or to a file in both cases `Ärztin` will be exported.

But if `$name` is inserted into the database I got the error:

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Incorrect string value: '\xE4rztin...' for column .......
```

If I write in the script:

```
$name = 'Ärztin';
$insert_import->execute($name)
```

or straight forwared

```
$insert_import->execute('Ärztin')
```

and run the script there is no error and `Ärztin` is written in column `name`.

Obviously, `$name` when decoded is not the same as when the string with umlaut is written directly into the scalar. What is the explanation for this and how can
I solve the problem?

Comment: Try `utf8::encode($name);` or `utf8::upgrade($name);` before execute. If that works, I'll answer with an explanation

Comment: I tried with `utf8::encode($name)`: It works! I'm so happy.